# Android widget cut off at the bottom

Tags: android, widget, size, provider

I have a 4x2 widget using the following layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottomLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:visibility="visible" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtInfo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:shadowColor="#777777"
        android:shadowDx="1"
        android:shadowDy="1"
        android:shadowRadius="0"
        android:text="Test"
        android:textColor="#f0f0f0"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The widget provider file defines width and height as

```
android:minWidth="294dp"
android:minHeight="110dp"
android:initialLayout="@layout/main_4x2"
android:resizeMode="horizontal"
android:previewImage="@drawable/widget_4x2"
android:widgetCategory="keyguard|home_screen"
android:updatePeriodMillis="0" >
```

The widget looks fine on most devices but is cut off on a few of them. Is there a problem with either the layout or widget provider definition?

Comment: Can you repost the code to the provider ? Seems like it got lost in the interwebs ;-)

Comment: I have modified the post and included the full provider info.